# Bazel: building a tree of dependencies

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I need to use bazel to manage our the source dependencies such that the final build product is purely a function of the toolchain, a vanishingly small number of files from the linux-distribution, and the source code itself. This means building things like libz, libssl, libcrypto, libcurl...

1. These dependences depend on each other
2. They have their own native (mostly autotools based) build systems, based on something like `./configure --prefix=foo && make -j && make install`.

It seems to me that Bazel is not well suited to this use case. In particular, we need to manually recreate the `make install` step for each library, in order to copy `make install` artifacts out of *execroot*. It's unclear to me how the next dependency reuses the products. So, for example, when building zlib, we produce `libz.a`, and a bunch of header files. Then, when building `libcrypto.a`, we need to modify `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` to point to the zlib "installation".

This strikes me as so pedantic that it's begging for code generation to generate the BUILD files.

Is there an alternative approach that doesn't require bespoke copying the "make install" logic into a genrule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at rules_foreign_cc (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc). This contains rules for integrating with foreign build systems (make, autotools+make, cmake, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately this is still experimental software, but I'll give it a go.